# Connecting 2 different programs in Java (each one has its main method)

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I have created 2 programs (Background and NrLojtareve) using Java GUI where each one of them creates a step of a game.  Each program has its own main method.

All I want to do is after executing the first program (NrLojtareve) which includes 4 radio buttons to display the other page, I created with the other program(Background).

So going from the first step of the game to the second.  So the handler of NrLojtareve class to call the Background class.

Can anyone show me how to call the second program from the first or how to display the second GUI after selecting a radio button from the first program?

Here is the code.

**Nrlojtareve.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Nrlojtareve extends JFrame {

    private JRadioButton a;
    private JRadioButton b;
    private JRadioButton c;
    private JRadioButton d;
    private ButtonGroup group ;
    private JLabel e;

    public Nrlojtareve() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        a=new JRadioButton("1");
        b=new JRadioButton("2");
        c=new JRadioButton("3");
        d=new JRadioButton("4");
        e=new JLabel("Choose the number of players!");
        add(a);
        add(b);
        add(c);
        add(d);
        add(e);
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(a);
        group.add(b);
        group.add(c);
        group.add(d);

        thehandler hand = new thehandler();
        a.addItemListener(hand);
        b.addItemListener(hand);
        c.addItemListener(hand);
        d.addItemListener(hand);
    }

    private class thehandler implements ItemListener {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Nrlojtareve elda = new Nrlojtareve();
        elda.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        elda.setSize(300,400);
        elda.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Back.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Back extends JFrame {

private Container pane;
    public Back() {
        super("title");
        setLayout(null);

        Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
        pane=new Container();

        //konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
        thehandler hand = new thehandler();

    }

     private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Back  d = new Back() ;

         d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         d.setSize(700,500);

         d.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm not your down voter, but also, please see edit to my answer for an example of playing around with your code.

Comment: Ok thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: You're welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these lines from the main method in the **Back** class to the end of the **Back** constructor. It should look like:

```
public Back(){
    super("title");
    setLayout(null);

    Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
    pane=new Container();

    thehandler hand=new thehandler();//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    setSize(700,500);
    setVisible(true);    
}
```

Then in your **Nrlojtareve** class put

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    Back back = new Back();
}
```

Also, you can remove the main method completely from the **Back** class.

Comment: Thanks!That's what I was asking for!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Comment: @user5827762: I'm glad you've got an answer, but I have to disagree. I've been doing heavy Swing coding for a number of years, and while this advice works, it's not a good design as the user will not like windows swapped at them. Much better is to swap views. Sorry, but I have to call it as I see it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I don't disagree with you at all. I was just trying to answer his question using the code base he already had. I did find your suggestions below to be very informative myself.

Comment: Another question please.What if I want to use elements from NrLojtareve into Back class?How can I do that?

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels I find you suggestions very helpful1 Thanks!But I have to use JFrame instead of JPanel.

Comment: These classes were for examples but my real programs are very long.I can't change all of the components to adapt JPanel

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- Avoid creating classes that extend JFrame. Doing this paints you into a corner and forces you to use the class as a JFrame.
- Instead gear your Swing GUI's towards creating JPanels. This will give you much greater flexibility since then you can place the JPanels into JFrames if you want to display them as stand alone GUI's or in JDialogs or JOptionPanes, or other JPanels.
- After doing this for the above code, create a 3rd JPanel that uses [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), and add the above JPanel GUI's to this "master" CardLayout using JPanel. Then you can swap your "views" easily using the CardLayout's `show(...)` method.
- Then create another class that has nothing in it but a main method, in the main method create your JFrame, add the master CardLayout-using JPanel to the JFrame, and display it.
- [CardLayout Tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Other advice:

- Avoid `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` like the plague as their use will lead to creation of rigid GUI's that can't be used inside of JScrollPane, are very difficult to extend, enhance and debug. Instead learn and use the layout managers.
- Another option is to display the first GUI as a modal dialog such as a JDialog.

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class CombinedGui {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Combined GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_PLAYERS = 4;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private ChoicePanel choicePanel = new ChoicePanel(MAX_PLAYERS);
    private BackPanel backPanel = new BackPanel();

    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(choicePanel, ChoicePanel.class.getName());
        add(backPanel, BackPanel.class.getName());

        choicePanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new ChoicePanelListener());
    }

    public void showView(String key) {
        cardLayout.show(this, key);
    }

    private class ChoicePanelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (ChoicePanel.PLAYER_COUNT.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                int playerCount = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
                backPanel.setPlayerCount(playerCount);
                showView(BackPanel.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BackPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.GREEN;
    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = 500;
    private static final String PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT = "Player Count is: ";
    private JLabel playerCountLabel = new JLabel(PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private int playerCount = 0;

    public BackPanel() {
        playerCountLabel.setFont(playerCountLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48));

        setBackground(BG);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(playerCountLabel);
    }

    public void setPlayerCount(int playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        playerCountLabel.setText(PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT + playerCount);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public int getPlayerCount() {
        return playerCount;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ChoicePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String PLAYER_COUNT = "player count";
    private int playerCount = -1;

    public ChoicePanel(int maximumPlayers) {
        JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose Player Count:");
        int gap = 20;
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, 2 * gap, gap, 2 * gap);
        Border compoundBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);
        centralPanel.setBorder(compoundBorder);
        for (int i = 0; i < maximumPlayers; i++) {
            String text = "" + (i + 1) + " Player";
            if (i > 0) {
                text += "s";
            }
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(text);
            radioButton.addActionListener(new RadioListener(i + 1));
            centralPanel.add(radioButton);
        }
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(centralPanel);        
    }

    public void setPlayerCount(int playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        firePropertyChange(PLAYER_COUNT, -1, playerCount);
    }

    public int getPlayerCount() {
        return playerCount;
    }

    private class RadioListener implements ActionListener {
        private int count;

        public RadioListener(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setPlayerCount(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Or for a modal dialog example, try:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CombinedGui {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Combined GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // !! frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_PLAYERS = 4;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private BackPanel backPanel = new BackPanel();

    public MainPanel2() {
        JButton getChoiceBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Select Number of Players") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MainPanel2.this);

                ChoicePanel choicePanel = new ChoicePanel(MAX_PLAYERS);
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(win, "Player Count Dialog", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                choicePanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if (ChoicePanel.PLAYER_COUNT.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                            int playerCount = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
                            backPanel.setPlayerCount(playerCount);
                            showView(BackPanel.class.getName());
                            dialog.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.add(choicePanel);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(getChoiceBtn);

        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(panel, "First Panel");
        add(backPanel, BackPanel.class.getName());

    }

    public void showView(String key) {
        cardLayout.show(this, key);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_PLAYERS = 4;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private ChoicePanel choicePanel = new ChoicePanel(MAX_PLAYERS);
    private BackPanel backPanel = new BackPanel();

    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(choicePanel, ChoicePanel.class.getName());
        add(backPanel, BackPanel.class.getName());

        choicePanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new ChoicePanelListener());
    }

    public void showView(String key) {
        cardLayout.show(this, key);
    }

    private class ChoicePanelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (ChoicePanel.PLAYER_COUNT.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                int playerCount = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
                backPanel.setPlayerCount(playerCount);
                showView(BackPanel.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BackPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.GREEN;
    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = 500;
    private static final String PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT = "Player Count is: ";
    private JLabel playerCountLabel = new JLabel(PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private int playerCount = 0;

    public BackPanel() {
        playerCountLabel.setFont(playerCountLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48));

        setBackground(BG);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(playerCountLabel);
    }

    public void setPlayerCount(int playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        playerCountLabel.setText(PLAYER_COUNT_TEXT + playerCount);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public int getPlayerCount() {
        return playerCount;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ChoicePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String PLAYER_COUNT = "player count";
    private int playerCount = -1;

    public ChoicePanel(int maximumPlayers) {
        JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose Player Count:");
        int gap = 20;
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, 2 * gap, gap, 2 * gap);
        Border compoundBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);
        centralPanel.setBorder(compoundBorder);
        for (int i = 0; i < maximumPlayers; i++) {
            String text = "" + (i + 1) + " Player";
            if (i > 0) {
                text += "s";
            }
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(text);
            radioButton.addActionListener(new RadioListener(i + 1));
            centralPanel.add(radioButton);
        }
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(centralPanel);        
    }

    public void setPlayerCount(int playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        firePropertyChange(PLAYER_COUNT, -1, playerCount);
    }

    public int getPlayerCount() {
        return playerCount;
    }

    private class RadioListener implements ActionListener {
        private int count;

        public RadioListener(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setPlayerCount(count);
        }
    }
}
```